# File upload form validation invalid

Tags: php, zend-framework

Current form:

```
$main = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
$kids = new Zend_Form_SubForm();

$number = $main->addElement(... attribs and so on ...);

$this->addSubForms(array('main'=>$main,'kids'=>$kids));
```

When I'm adding this file upload fields to my form:

```
for($index = 1; $index <= 10; $index++) {

            $name = 'Image'.$index;
            $label = 'Image'.$index;

            $image = new Zend_Form_Element_File($name);
            $image->setLabel($label)
                ->addValidator('Count', true, 1)
                ->addValidator('Size', false, 10485760)
                ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,jpeg,tif,tiff,eps');
            $kids->addElement($image);
}
```

The following part in my controller will fail:

```
$post = $this->_request->getPost();
if($form->isValid($post) )
```

And there will not be any formerror outputted.

Error Reporting is on, also the following part (if is not valid) does not return any warning or error message!

```
else {  
    print_r($form->getMessages());
    print_r($form->getErrors());
    print_r($form->getErrorMessages());
}
```

I'm using the standard Zend form isvalid function:

```
public function isValid($data)
{

    $isValid = parent::isValid($data);
    return $isValid;

}
```

Whats could be wrong here?

*By the way:
Printing out the post data looks fine as well.
And I already updated Zend to version 1.12.13 without any improvements :(*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody is interested and may be has the same problem, I finally got the **solution**:

**Solution 1:**
The problem was, that the submitted $_FILES was limited to 20 file upload fields. See php ini `max_file_uploads` -> http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads.
And that was why Zend always said that the form is not validated. Strange because no error message that gives you a hint.

Btw, if you installed the php extension `suhosin` the parameter from php is overwritten: It carries it's own upload limit: `suhosin.upload.max_uploads`

**Solution 2:**
The other solution is to use `$form->isValidPartial` instead of `$form->isValid`.
In this case the not existing file elements are not beeing validated.

Please also have a look at the **hotfix** here, if you submitting empty form fields:
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11707